# Binary Genetic Algorithm in R, with strong cardinality constraints

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to use package GA in R for a problem where I must find the best combination of 4 out of 56 instruments. Obviously the number of combinations of 4 instruments out of 56 runs into the hundreds of thousands, therefore a brute force approach is out of the question, especially that the target function itself contains another optimization and is slow. So the Genetic Algorithm seems suitable. However the ga function, even with "type = binary", does not seem to be able to have a cardinality constraint. Instead the [documentation](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiwmez9kuTYAhVFOhQKHaqkAcoQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv053i04%2Fv53i04.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2vC6SjPkIANb-nUDSZLeJ9) (page 21) suggests using AIC or BIC information criteria by putting in a penalty in the objective function but I *already know* that I only want 4. Here is my current code:

```
gaopter <- function(xx) {
    a4 <- ay[, xx == 1]
    a4r <- ayr[, xx == 1]

    opter <- function(x) {
    # optimize for sd over vol, where a4 is a subcolumn of ay
        rets <- a4r %*% x
        outs <- a4 %*% x
        sdouts <- sd(outs)
        tomake <- (abs(last(outs) - mean(outs)) / sdouts - 1) * sdouts
        -(tomake / sd(rets))
        #(last(outs) - mean(outs)) / sd(outs)
    }
    optim(rep(1, ncol(a4)), opter)$value
}

ga(type = "binary", fitness = gaopter, nBits = ncol(ay), maxiter = 1000, run = 20000)
```

Variables ay and ayr are matrices of 56 vectors and their daily returns, respectively, so what I am trying to optimize for, above is: the best linear combination of 4 of the 56 vectors, such that their daily returns standard deviation is minimized, while at the same time, the last point in the series is as far as possible from the mean. The above code will just find the best combination of the 56 vectors that satisfy the above, without any cardinality constraint.

The major problem with a low cardinality constraint such as 4 is that with a random binary vector of 0s and 1s 56 in length, it is almost never going to give me only 4 ones with the rest zeros in a random combination, and so putting in some kind of cardinality == 4 penalty will just mean nothing ever gets run. What can I do to limit cardinality of the combinations to 4, using package GA or another?

Comment: While $\binom{56}{4}=367290$ this seems like a lot, you might consider brute force anyway as the relatively long runtime might be eventually beneficial. Keep in mind that processing time for large datasets is long no matter how you put it, especially when running complex optimizations such as described.

Comment: thanks @Spätzle but this is just a test run for much larger problems, which could reach 20 instruments out of 3000 choices (=1345040530198517819693808858706736027904707525227350 combinations), ie trillions of trillions, at which time I will be running the algo on a GPU farm.

Comment: Have considered using simulated annealing?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington I have to admit to being a relative newby to discrete optimization, and while I know the principles behind simulated annealing, I cannot remember having come across the idea that it is useful for combinatorial style optimizations with cardinality constraints as per question? Very happy to be proven wrong... if you can show me an R or Python package and/or a paper I'd be very happy to consider.

Comment: Again, I can't comment .. so I answer here to the last comment ...
Here is an exemple of using simulated anealing on a combinatorial problem :
[travaling salesman](http://toddwschneider.com/posts/traveling-salesman-with-simulated-annealing-r-and-shiny/)
Searching through google scholar, you may find a lot of paper on this subject.
R offers some usefull packages :
stats (see SANN)
GenSA
dclone More generally, you may be interested by this :
[optimization CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)

Comment: Do you have to use Genetic Algorithm or any optimization algorithm will do?

Comment: @t.f yes any algo will do. GA seemed to be appropriate, but I am quite happy to take advice on other algorithms or techniques.

Comment: can you upload a sample data set?

Comment: @t.f how do I do that? You mean host it somehwere or is it hostable on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try and solve it using the Cross entropy algorithm. It is a method suggest by Reuven Rubenstein [CE Method](http://iew3.technion.ac.il/CE/).

Basically the idea is to keep good solutions and deduce on the parameters based on them. So in general suppose you want to find the 4 lowest SD. the algorithm will be as following: 
1. Create a vector of probabilities for each instrument. 
2. Simulate multiple solutions. 
3. Take the best $\xi$ solutions. 
4. Update the probability vector.

Small Simulation.

```
> ## Creating Data
> 
> sig.vec      <- rep(1, 200) 
> low.sig.ind  <- sample(200, 4)
> sig.vec[low.sig.ind] <- 0.4 
> 
> ret <- t(replicate(300, rnorm(200, rep(0, 200), sig.vec)))
> 
> 
> 
> low.sig.ind
[1] 197 152  49  51
> ### Prepare running CE 
> iter     <- 100
> prob.vec <- runif(200) 
> sol.mat  <- matrix(NA, nrow = iter, ncol = 5)
> prob.list <- list()
> for (i in 1:10) {
+   ## Creating Sol 
+   for (j in 1:iter) {
+     temp.choice    <- sample(4, x = 200, prob = prob.vec)
+     sol.mat[j, ]   <- c(temp.choice, sd(apply(ret[,temp.choice], 1, sum)))
+   }
+   temp.tab <- table(factor(sol.mat[sol.mat[,5] <= quantile(sol.mat[,5], 0.1), 1:4], 
+                            levels = 1:200)) 
+   prob.vec <- temp.tab / sum(temp.tab)
+   prob.list[[i]] <- prob.vec
+ }
> 
> prob.vec[prob.vec == 0.25]

  10   49   72  152 
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

So it found the correct ones, off course this is a toy example.

Comment: `iter` is not defined in this example and this example doesn't even seem to run...

Comment: it is working now

Answer (score 2):

An implementation of the genetic algorithm for this kind of task is in the `kofnGA` package, which is described in [Wolters (2015)](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v068.c01). This implementation allows one to specify `n`, the total number of units, and `k`, the desired number of units to be chosen, and returns a vector containing the indices of the optimal solution.

In your example, the code would look like the following:

```r
gaopter <- function(i) {
    a4 <- ay[, i]
    a4r <- ayr[, i]

    opter <- function(x) {
    # optimize for sd over vol, where a4 is a subcolumn of ay
        rets <- a4r %*% x
        outs <- a4 %*% x
        sdouts <- sd(outs)
        tomake <- (abs(last(outs) - mean(outs)) / sdouts - 1) * sdouts
        -(tomake / sd(rets))
        #(last(outs) - mean(outs)) / sd(outs)
    }
    optim(rep(1, ncol(a4)), opter)$value
}

opt <- kofnGA(n = 56, k = 4, OF = gaopter, ngen = 1000)
```

Note that the objective function has been modified to take in a vector of indices rather than a vector of 0/1 integers. This function has fewer options than `GA::ga()`, like early termination, but it is still relatively fast (and can be parallelized).